# Point in the mesh messing up the shader (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh

I have been working on this project of mine for a while now and I noticed this part of the mesh not rendering correctly on Cycles. I thought it was a flipped normal at first but that wasnt the case. I even recreated the mesh again but the problem still persisted.

Things I have already checked about:

- Non-manifold geometry
- Superimposed points
- Bad UV wrap (shader has no textures)
- Non-quad based geometry
- Updated blender from 2.92 to 2.93 and the problem stays

Any sort of help will be appreciated :D Thanks

[image: Mesh in Cycles and Eevee]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you have enabled *Anisotropic* shading in the *Principled BSDF*.

[image]

This wouldn't show up in Eevee, so that would explain that part of it.

Comment: I just checked and the shader has anisotropic at a value of 0. Kinda stumped on this one

Comment: Looking at it again... Given your edit mode view, I'm unsure how you've got this subdivision surface on it while keeping the shape intact.  Might be worth it to save a minimum viable .blend showcasing the issue and upload it to blend-exchange.com

Edit your post to include the code snippet they provide you.

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/7jmGzPR) is how it appears fully rendered in Cycles

Comment: Never mind, I am blind apparently. Theres was another shader connected to the mix-shader node that was messing it up (it had anisotropic turned up).

Allen Simpson was right. Thanks a lot man

Comment: Oh, nice.  Glad you solved it.